# name of a special map sought

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions, definition, function-and-relation-composition

I'm playing with some mathematical stuff. More precisely, I'm considering maps

$ T \colon X \to X$

for an arbitrary set $X$, where $T$ has the property:

$T^2 = T \circ T = -T$.

In other words : $T^2$ maps to its negative value.

My question : Is there a name (designation) for maps mentioned above?

Thanks in advance.

edit: Maybe there is no official name for that. I tried to google it, but I found nothing helpful. For me, this is an interesting subject and I just wanted to know if there is a designation or if there are already some scientific results for such maps.

Comment: On an arbitrary set, what does $-$ mean? You should assume that $X$ is an abelian group or so.

Comment: well, $X$ could be a vector space. But this is not the point here. I'm only interested in a similar mathematical definition, a name/designation for maps with the property I mentioned in my post.

Comment: It looks a bit like the Fourier transform, which is four-periodic.

Comment: If it weren't for the minus sign, $T$ would be [_idempotent_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). With the minus sign, a simple name might therefore be _skew-idempotent_. A search of this phrase through Google Scholar does give some hits to that effect. The phrase _anti-idempotent_ would serve the same effect.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If it weren't for the minus sign, $T$ would be [*idempotent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). With the minus sign, a simple name might therefore be *skew-* or *anti-idempotent*. A search of these phrases through Google Scholar does give some hits to that effect, with more for the latter than the former.